# When using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning the toView buttons are unable to interact with

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, transition

I'm facing this issue with my custom UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning class. When the animation is done and the toView is presented the elements (buttons etc) in it are not able to receive interaction.

The custom class code is like this:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 1.0;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext;
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    CGRect finalFrameForVC = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toViewController];
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 0);
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0 initialSpringVelocity:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.5;
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, finalFrameForVC.size.width, finalFrameForVC.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

And from the view the transition is called like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAction"]) {
        FiltersViewController *filterView = (FiltersViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        filterView.transitioningDelegate = self;
    }
}

-(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    self.filtersPresentAnimationController = [[FiltersPresentAnimationController alloc] init];
    return self.filtersPresentAnimationController;
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? It works perfectly fine when I remove the segue identifier from the segue.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to tell the transitionContext that the transition is done.

So missing this in the finished animation block

```
[transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
```